# Content Security Policy: The page’s settings blocked the loading of a resource at inline (“style-src”). on Firefox

Tags: reactjs, content-security-policy, bluemix-app-scan

I have my CSP added as below in my code

```
res.header('Content-Security-Policy',
        "default-src 'self' ; style-src 'self' '<hashvalue>';" +
        "script-src 'self' '<hashvalue>';" +
        "font-src 'self' data: fonts.gstatic.com;" +
        "img-src 'self';" +
        "frame-src 'self'; " +
        "object-src 'none';" +
        "frame-ancestors 'none';"+
        "connect-src 'none';"
    );
```

After adding this my UI does not load on Firefox

And even though I have set this CSP I get Appscan issue for CSP as

'AppScan detected that the Content-Security-Policy response header is missing or with an insecure policy, which increases exposure to various cross-site injection attacks'

Your help is highly appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I know if you explore this with the Inspector on Chrome it will tell you exactly what resources are blocked by the CSP and which CSP rules were violated. I don't think the Firefox inspector goes into this much detail, unfortunately.

Comment: It works perfectly fine on Chrome, The UI gets rendered and works as expected

Comment: what does redbot.org tell you?

Comment: You may have to disable some firefox browser addons to check if it's caused by an addon?

Comment: I have disabled all the addons, even I had thought it might be because of some addons but still no luck

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was able to resolve the issue by completely removing style-src which was being over protected by Content Security Policy headers

Comment: Perhaps think about writing and accepting an answer :)